# Mongoose nested schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating an app where you log workouts and I'm having some problems with Mongoose.

I have two schemas, one for workouts and one for exercises. When the user adds a new exercise, I want it to be stored inside the workout, and I've been trying this in a bunch of ways.

For now, the exercises are saved in a different collection in my MongoDB (don't know if this is the best way to do it), and I thought that it should save the exercise inside the workout.exercises, but there is only the objectID. How do I resolve this? Have looked at the populate function, but can't figure out how to get it to work.

**addExercises**

```
export function addExercise(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.exercise.title) {
    res.status(403).end();
  }

  const newExercise = new Exercise(req.body.exercise);

  // Let's sanitize inputs
  newExercise.title = sanitizeHtml(newExercise.title);
  newExercise.cuid = cuid();
  newExercise.sets = [];

  newExercise.save((err, saved) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
  });

  Workout
    .findOneAndUpdate(
      {cuid: req.body.exercise.workoutCUID},
      {$push: {exercises: newExercise}},
      {upsert: true, new: true},
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
      });
}
```

**getExercises**

```
export function getExercises(req, res) {
  Workout.findOne({cuid: req.params.cuid}).exec((err, workout) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    console.log(workout);
    let exercises = workout.exercises;
    res.json({exercises});
  });
}
```

**Workout**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Exercise = require('./exercise');

const workoutSchema = new Schema({
  title:     {type: 'String', required: true},
  cuid:      {type: 'String', required: true},
  slug:      {type: 'String', required: true},
  userID:    {type: 'String', required: true},
  exercises: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise' }],
  date:      {type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true},
});

export default mongoose.model('Workout', workoutSchema);
```

**Exercise**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Workout = require('./workout');

const exerciseSchema = new Schema({
  title:       {type: 'String', required: true},
  cuid:        {type: 'String', required: true},
  workoutCUID: {type: 'String', required: true},
  sets:        {type: 'Array', "default": [], required: true}
});

export default mongoose.model('Exercise', exerciseSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `Workout` schema, you declare the type of the `Exercises` field to be `[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise' }]`. This means that this field should be an array of Mongoose ObjectId's.

It appears that you are attempting to add the whole `exercise` object to the workout's `exercises` field, rather than just the ObjectId. Try modifying it this way:

```
const newExercise = new Exercise(req.body.exercise);

// Let's sanitize inputs
newExercise.title = sanitizeHtml(newExercise.title);
newExercise.cuid = cuid();
newExercise.sets = [];

newExercise.save((err, saved) => {
  if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
  // Nest the Workout update in here to ensure that the new exercise saved correctly before proceeding
  Workout
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {cuid: req.body.exercise.workoutCUID},
        // push just the _id, not the whole object
        {$push: {exercises: newExercise._id}}, 
        {upsert: true, new: true},
        function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        });

});
```

Now that you correctly have the ObjectId saved in the exercises field, `.populate` should work when you query the workout:

```
Workout.findById(id).populate("exercises").exec((err, workout) => {
 // handle error and do stuff with the workout
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 Workout.findById(req.params.id).populate("exercises").exec((err,workout) =>{
 res.status(200).json(workout);
})
```

It should work this way